# Removing control from panel doesn't remove it from the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a routine where I loop recursively through all the controls on a form and process some code on some of them.

I add and remove controls through the use of the screen depending on selections the user makes.

I found that `panel.Controls.Remove(control1)` didn't actually remove it from the form. When I would run the routine that loops recursively through the controls on the form, the control I thought I had remove was still being found.

It didn't "disappear" until I did:

`panel.Controls.Remove(control1);

this.Controls.Remove(control1)`

Is this expected? Can someone explain this to me, and or point me to somewhere that explains control behavior in Windows Forms.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure this is *not* expected behavior. When you say it "was still being found", do you mean that you could still see it on the screen? Are you sure that the form had been redrawn (repainted) since you called the `Remove` method?

Comment: Did you try enclosing them in `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout`, maybe the form didn't get redrawn

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `Controls.Remove` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Yeah sorry, fixed.

Comment: @CodyGray: I mean that the next time I recursively looped through the controls on the form, it was found in the loop. It's not visually on the form, I can't see it.

Comment: Check that the control hasn't been added to the Controls lists in both the form and panel.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the control has the form as its Parent, not the panel.  These kind of accidents tend to happen easily with the designer.  You can use View + Other Windows + Document Layout to get a good view of the child-parent relationships.  You can use drag+drop in this list to fix.